# have git track changes on a renamed file (with new file to complicate matters)

Tags: python, git

We have a file that contains models that live in `root_dir/model/__init__.py`. This is obviously not ideal and it is preferable that this code lives in  `root_dir/models.py`. The problem is that there are older versions of this that need to be maintained, and I expect that there will be changes to the older models that need to be merged forward.

If I use `git mv root_dir/model/__init__.py root_dir/models.py` changes to `__init__.py` are merged forward into `models.py` as expected.

There is a problem though: `root_dir/model/` still requires an `__init__.py` and when I create one, the merge forward no longer works and leads to challenging merge conflicts.

I am hoping there is some other option that I am missing, but have accepted that this might just be something painful we have to live with for a release cycle or two.

Comment: Could you patch the program so that whenever it's running the older version, it loads `root_dir/model/__init__.py` instead of `root_dir/models.py`? Then, you can just leave the `__init__.py` file as it is now instead of overwriting it with a new blank file

Comment: This is kind of how things are now. The problem is that we will need to fix things in `__init__.py` in the older stream and merge those changes forward into the new `models.py`. Additionally, I specifically don't want that code in the init (lastest version) anymore to avoid importing it unnecessarily.

Comment: Does it not work if you do it in two separate commits?

Comment: Nope. I tried 2 commits, same issue.